# Как создать такую фиксированную кнопку меню, меняющую цвет при проктурке?

Tags: css

Есть страница, у которой чередуются цвета блоков. В каждом блоке должна быть  кнопка открытия меню: в черном блоке белая кнопка, в белом - черная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать такой эффект, чтобы при прокрутке страницы кнопка меняла цвет в зависимости от блока. Будто одна кнопка заходит за границу родительского блока, а другая выезжает. Пытался сделать через `overflow: hidden`, но на кнопку с фиксированным позиционированием это не действует.

[Пример](http://nemiroff.vodka/?valid=yes) того, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без javascript, вам это не удастся решить.
Отслеживайте scroll, через событие window.onscroll, или воспользуйтесь jquery.scroll(), а после изменяйте стиль на какой нужно.

Еще могу посоветовать .scrollTo.